# image does not respect lower page margin in twocolumn document

Tags: margins, includegraphics, footer

From time to time, I run into the problem, that my text margins seem not to be respected.

See an example here:
[image]
The image (shaded green) does not respect my lower text margin. Part of the footer line violates with the image.

Some code excerpts:

```
% preamble
%!TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    top=1.6cm,
    bottom=1.6cm,
    left=1.2cm,
    right=1.2cm,
    headheight=14pt,
    headsep=0.28cm,
    footskip=0.65cm,
    showframe
}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5cm}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\fancypagestyle{defaultHeadFootWithLine}{
    \fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
    \fancyhead[L]{\sffamily header blabla}
    \fancyhead[C]{\sffamily \MyTitle}
    \fancyhead[R]{\sffamily \MyDate}
    \fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
    \fancyfoot[L]{\sffamily school blabla}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\sffamily \thepage\  von \pageref*{LastPage}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\sffamily \MyAuthor}
}

% in document
\subsubsection{Halbaddierer}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{DT_00_HalfAdder.png}
```

Do you have any idea, what the problem could be? What am I doing wrong?
Here's the complete code on overleaf: `https://de.overleaf.com/read/xxxmksynjtdz`

All the code here:

```
%!TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{article}


% --- packages --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % Https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf
\usepackage{tabularray} % for table formatting
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % underline mit \uline
\usepackage{mathtools}  % must be loaded before fonts

% --- Fonts and Encoding ----------------------------------------------------------------------


% --- Math -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{physics}    % derivatives etc.
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction, fraction-function=\frac} 

% --- Sprache ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[nswissgerman]{babel}    % Neue Rechtschreibung Schweiz

% --- Title -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{authoraftertitle} % access \author, \title and \date via \MyAuthor, ...
\title{Digitaltechnik (DT) Zusammenfassung}
\author{the author}
\date{\today}

% --- Page Setup ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{geometry}
% https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Page_size_and_margins
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    top=1.6cm,
    bottom=1.6cm,
    left=1.2cm,
    right=1.2cm,
    headheight=14pt,
    headsep=0.28cm,
    footskip=0.65cm,
    showframe
}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5cm}

% --- Header and Footer -----------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\fancypagestyle{defaultHeadFootWithLine}{
    \fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
    \fancyhead[L]{\sffamily header blabla}
    \fancyhead[C]{\sffamily \MyTitle}
    \fancyhead[R]{\sffamily \MyDate}
    %\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hrule height 0.5pt} % Line
    \fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
    \fancyfoot[L]{\sffamily school blabla}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\sffamily \thepage\  von \pageref*{LastPage}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\sffamily \MyAuthor}
    %\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hrule height 0.5pt \vspace{-0.5mm}}  % Line
}

% --- Headings Spacing ------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{titlesec}
% Adjust styles
%\titleformat{\part}[hang]%{\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}{}{0em}{}
%   {\Huge\sffamily\fontseries{k}\selectfont}{\partformat}{1em}{\vspace*{0pt}}
%   \newcommand{\partformat}{\partname\ \thepart}
\titleformat{\section}      {\sffamily\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{} % remove section number (instead of {\thesection}{1em}{})
\titleformat{\subsection}   {\sffamily\large\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\color{black!86}\sffamily\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}   {\color{black!86}\sffamily\bfseries}

% Adjust spacing around section titles
%\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\section}         {0pt}{6pt}{0pt}   % indent, before, after
\titlespacing{\subsection}      {0pt}{6pt}{0pt}   % indent, before, after
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}   {0pt}{6pt}{0pt}   % indent, before, after
\titlespacing{\paragraph}       {0pt}{6pt}{0pt}   % indent, before, after

% Table of Contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % Set the table of contents depth to 2

% --- Paragraph Spacing -----------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlength{\currparskip}            
\setlength{\currparskip}{4pt plus1pt}   % default paragraph spacing
\usepackage[skip=\currparskip, indent=0pt]{parskip}


% --- Table Spacing ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\SetTblrInner{rowsep=2pt}

% --- Quotes ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[
left = \flqq{},
right = \frqq{},
leftsub = \flq{},
rightsub = \frq{}
]{dirtytalk}

% --- Configure graphicx ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % for wrapping images around text

% --- Date Styles -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{datetime2}
\DTMsetup{useregional=num}

% --- Hyperlinks ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document} %=============================================================================
    \pagestyle{defaultHeadFootWithLine}
    
    % --- Title Page ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    {
        \sffamily
        \maketitle
        \tableofcontents
    }
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \clearpage 
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    
    % --- Content ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \section{Grundlagen}
    \section{Placeholder}
    \subsection{Analog vs. Digital}
    analog: zeit- und wert\uline{kontinuierlich}, digital: zeit- und wert\uline{diskret}
    
    \subsubsection{Vorteile Digitaltechnik}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Robustheit gegenüber Störungen
        \item Miniaturisierung möglich, Aufwand an Transistoren nicht limitierend
        \item Automatisierung beim Entwickeln von IC's $\rightarrow$ Massenproduktion
        \item Leistungsfähigkeit aufgrund hoher Taktraten
    \end{itemize}
    
    \subsection{FPGA}
    Array aus generischen logischen Blöcken, wobei jeder Block aus D-FF, LUT und MUX besteht. \\
    Hinzu kommen Makrozellen (DSP, RAM, PLL, IO)
    
    \section{Schaltalgebra}
    \subsection{Operationen}
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]
        \item !: NOT
        \item \&: AND
        \item \#: OR
    \end{itemize}
    
    \subsection{Normalformen}
    \subsubsection{Beispiel WT}
    \begin{tblr}{width=\columnwidth, colspec={X[c] X[c] X[c] | X[c]}}
        C & B & A & Y \\
        \hline
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1
    \end{tblr}
    
    \subsubsection{Disjunktive Normalform (1er)}
    Die disjunkte Normalform ist die OR-Verknüpfung aller 1-Terme.
    
    \verb|Y = (!C & !B & A) # (C & B & A)|
    
    \subsubsection{Konjunktive Normalform (0er)}
    Die konjunktive Normalform ist die AND-Verknüpfung aller 0-Terme, wobei die Terme mit inv. Eingängen OR-verknüpft werden.
    
    \verb|Y = !( (!C & B & A) # (C & B & !A) )| \\
    \texttt{\phantom{Y }= (C \# !B \# !A) \& (!C \# !B \# A)} 
    
    \section{Binäre Arithmetik}
    \subsubsection{Halbaddierer}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{DT_00_HalfAdder.png}
    
    \subsubsection{Volladdierer}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{DT_00_HalfAdder.png}

    
    
\end{document}
```

And the image:
[image]

Comment: Hello, just a question: Do you not want to use a float environment for including the images? This would certainly avoid this issue.

Comment: Off-topic: Why do you suppress section numbering in the body of the document but not in the table of contents?

Comment: @lukeflo Thanks for this suggestion. I've always included images directly inside the text because I did not see a reason to use an environment like `figure`. 
Seems like I was wrong assuming the environment is not needed.

Comment: @Mico I suppress section numbering because I want this document to be lean and clear. I could also use the star commands, but with the disadvantage that the section does not appear in the TOC. And I didn't take the time to make the numbering disappear in the TOC.

Answer (score 0):

Encasing the graphs in `figure` environments appears to be helpful, at least for the code example at hand.

[image]

```
%!TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.

% --- packages --

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} % optional but recommended
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray} % for table formatting
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % underline mit \uline
\usepackage{mathtools}  % must be loaded before fonts % you sure 'bout this??

% --- Fonts and Encoding -------------------------


% --- Math -----
\usepackage{physics}    % derivatives etc.
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction, fraction-function=\frac} 

% --- Sprache ---
\usepackage[nswissgerman]{babel} % Rechtschreibung CH

% --- Title -----
\usepackage{authoraftertitle} % access \author, \title and \date via \MyAuthor, ...
\title{Digitaltechnik (DT) Zusammenfassung}
\author{the author}
\date{\today}

% --- Page Setup 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    top=1.6cm,
    bottom=1.6cm,
    left=1.2cm,
    right=1.2cm,
    headheight=14pt,
    headsep=0.28cm,
    footskip=0.65cm,
    showframe
}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5cm}

% --- Header and Footer --------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\fancypagestyle{defaultHeadFootWithLine}{
    \fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
    \fancyhead[L]{\sffamily header blabla}
    \fancyhead[C]{\sffamily \MyTitle}
    \fancyhead[R]{\sffamily \MyDate}
    %\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hrule height 0.5pt} % Line
    \fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
    \fancyfoot[L]{\sffamily school blabla}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\sffamily \thepage\  von \pageref*{LastPage}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\sffamily \MyAuthor}
    %\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hrule height 0.5pt \vspace{-0.5mm}}  % Line
}

% --- Headings Spacing ---------------------------
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}      {\sffamily\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{} % remove section number (instead of {\thesection}{1em}{})
\titleformat{\subsection}   {\sffamily\large\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\color{black!86}\sffamily\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}   {\color{black!86}\sffamily\bfseries}

\titlespacing{\section}         {0pt}{6pt}{0pt}   % indent, before, after
\titlespacing{\subsection}      {0pt}{6pt}{0pt}   % indent, before, after
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}   {0pt}{6pt}{0pt}   % indent, before, after
\titlespacing{\paragraph}       {0pt}{6pt}{0pt}   % indent, before, after

% Table of Contents appearance:
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 

\usepackage{enumitem}

% --- Paragraph Spacing --------------------------
\newlength{\currparskip}            
\setlength{\currparskip}{4pt plus1pt}   % default paragraph spacing
\usepackage[skip=\currparskip, indent=0pt]{parskip}


% --- Table Spacing ------------------------------
\SetTblrInner{rowsep=2pt}

% --- Quotes ----
\usepackage[
  left     = \flqq{},
  right    = \frqq{},
  leftsub  = \flq{},
  rightsub = \frq{}
 ]{dirtytalk}

% --- Configure graphicx -------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % for wrapping images around text

% --- Date Styles --------------------------------
\usepackage{datetime2}
\DTMsetup{useregional=num}

% --- Hyperlinks 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}


\begin{document}     
\pagestyle{defaultHeadFootWithLine}
    
% --- Title Page 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    {
        \sffamily
        \maketitle
        \tableofcontents
    }
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
% --- Content ---

\clearpage 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
    
    \section{Grundlagen}
    
    \section{Placeholder}
    
    \subsection{Analog vs. Digital}
    analog:  zeit- und wert\uline{kontinuierlich}, 
    digital: zeit- und wert\uline{diskret}
    
    \subsubsection{Vorteile Digitaltechnik}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Robustheit gegenüber Störungen
    \item Miniaturisierung möglich, Aufwand 
          an Transistoren nicht limitierend
    \item Automatisierung beim Entwickeln von IC's 
          $\to$ Massenproduktion
    \item Leistungsfähigkeit aufgrund hoher Taktraten
    \end{itemize}
    
    \subsection{FPGA}
    
    Array aus generischen logischen Blöcken, wobei jeder Block aus D-FF, LUT und MUX besteht. 
    
    Hinzu kommen Makrozellen (DSP, RAM, PLL, IO)
    
    \section{Schaltalgebra}
    
    \subsection{Operationen}
    
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item !: NOT
    \item \&: AND
    \item \#: OR
    \end{itemize}
    
    
    \subsection{Normalformen}
    
    \subsubsection{Beispiel WT}
    
    \begin{tblr}{width=\columnwidth, colspec={X[c] X[c] X[c] | X[c]}}
        C & B & A & Y \\
        \hline
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1
    \end{tblr}
    
    \subsubsection{Disjunktive Normalform (1er)}
    
    Die disjunkte Normalform ist die 
    OR-Verknüpfung aller 1-Terme.
    
    \verb|Y = (!C & !B & A) # (C & B & A)|
    
    
    \subsubsection{Konjunktive Normalform (0er)}
    
    Die konjunktive Normalform ist die AND-Verknüpfung aller 0-Terme, wobei die Terme mit inv. Eingängen OR-verknüpft werden.
    
    \verb|Y = !( (!C & B & A) # (C & B & !A) )| \\
    \texttt{\phantom{Y }= (C \# !B \# !A) \& (!C \# !B \# A)} 
    
    
    \section{Binäre Arithmetik}
    
    \subsubsection{Halbaddierer}
    
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{DT_00_HalfAdder.png}
    \end{figure}
    
    
    \newpage % <-- force a column break
    \subsubsection{Volladdierer}
    
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{DT_00_HalfAdder.png}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Could you explain me, why using figure is preferable? I‘ve never heard that using \includegraphics without environment is not recommended…

Comment: @PascalH. - I’m not claiming that encasing the graphs in floating environments will *always* be the way to go. My intuition for why it appears to work for the example at hand is that it gives LaTeX some additional degrees of freedom for its search.